# Node.js / Express.js / ejs + WordPress or any CMS

Tags: node.js, wordpress, express, ejs

I have a question about CMS, currently I developed a website on Node.JS server using Express.Js and EJS.
The thing is I'm pretty bad for webdesign and I want to know if it's possible to use CMS like Wordpress to construct my FrontEnd ?
I read than WordPress using Apache/php and couldn't work with Node.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/) for example, will allow you to use the API from most CMS and use them in your own React app